# Perl - Encapsulate data from file, with regex exprex doesn't work without $/ = "\n\n"

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a problem with record separator of following perl script.

This perl script works as following:

1) If exist, it read a .rotaton_statistics file with following entries (filename,inode,Max n. of rows)

2) It encapsulate record with a specific regex, from all logrotate_*.log file

2a)If a .rotation_statistics exist, it start from the next line to the value *Max n. of rows* content into this statistics_file

2b)If a .rotation_statistics not exist, it start from 0 row of my logorotate*.log file.

3) It write new .rotation_statistics file, with all information updated

4) It split al data from @s_user array (@event array sorted by username) into "parse_log.csv" into a directory named as YYYY-MM (based on the year-month of my specific event)

**Bug details:**

In the specific, my loading events from logrotate_*.log files (line 42)  works only if i put $/ = "\n\n"; (at line 56).
With this separator, my skip row instruction doesn't work, because my row "$. " have a different relationship compared to $jumprow (that works with $line of file).

**SKIP ROW Instructions:**

> my $jumprow = 0; $jumprow = $older_count{$INPUT}[0] if $currentinode
>   == $inode;

I have to remove line 56 of my code to solve this problem, but, if i do that, my @events array it remains empty.

Could you make me understand where I'm wrong?

```perl
    #!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

# Dynamic Variables
my %older_count;
my %older_inode;
my @newer_filelist;
my @events;

my $OLD_IN_FILE = "";

# Static Variables
# Directories
my $IN_DIR               = "/tmp/appo/log";    # Input Directories
my $OUTPUT_LOG_DIRECTORY = "/tmp/appo/A14";    # Output directory

# Files
my $SPLITTED_OUTFILE = "parse_log.csv";           # Splitted by month output file
my $R_STATS          = ".rotation_statistics";    # Rotation Statistic file

## MAIN

# Loading old statistics
if (-e $R_STATS) { 
    open (STAT_FILE, $R_STATS) or die $!;
    while( <STAT_FILE> ) {
        my @lines = split /\n/;
        my ($file, $inode, $nrows ) = $lines[0] =~ /\A(.\w.*);(\d.*);(\d.*)/;   # Encapsulate values
        push @{ $older_count{$file} }, $nrows;
        push @{ $older_inode{$file} }, $inode;
    }
    close (STAT_FILE);
}

# Loading new events from log
foreach my $INPUT (glob("$IN_DIR/logrotate_*.log")) {
    my $inode = (stat($INPUT))[1];
    my $currentinode = $older_inode{$INPUT}[0];
    my $jumprow = 0;
    $jumprow = $older_count{$INPUT}[0] if $currentinode == $inode;

    # Get current file stastistics
    if ($INPUT ne $OLD_IN_FILE) {
        my $count=(split /\s+/, `wc -l $INPUT`)[0];
        push @newer_filelist, {filename => $INPUT, inode => $inode, count => $count };

    # Log opening
    open my $fh, '<', $INPUT ) or die $!;

    # I have a problem with this separator
    $/ = "\n\n";    # record separator
    # I have a problem with this separator

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        next unless $. > $jumprow;

        # Log processing
        my @lines = split /\n/;
        my $i     = 0;

        foreach my $lines ( @lines ) {

            # Take only Authentication rows and skip others
            if ( $lines[$i] =~ m/\A#\d.\d.+#\d{4}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3}#\+\d+#\w+#\/\w+\/\w+\/Authentication/ ) {

                # Shows only LOGIN/LOGOUT access type and exclude GUEST users
                if ( $lines[ $i + 2 ] =~ m/Login/ || $lines[ $i + 2 ] =~ m/Logout/ && $lines[ $i + 3 ] !~ m/Guest/ ) {

                    my ( $y, $m, $d, $time ) = $lines[$i] =~ /\A#\d.\d.+#(\d{4})\s(\d{2})\s(\d{2})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3})/;
                    my ( $action ) = $lines[ $i + 2 ] =~ /(\w+)/;
                    my ( $user )   = $lines[ $i + 3 ] =~ /\w+:\s(.+)/;
                    push @events, {
                        date   => "$y/$m/$d",
                        time   => $time,
                        action => $action,
                        user   => $user
                    };  # Array loader
                }
            }
            else {
                next;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $OLD_IN_FILE = $INPUT;
    }
    close( $fh );
}

# Print Log statistics for futher elaborations
open( STAT_FILE, '>', $R_STATS ) or die $!;
foreach my $my_filelist ( @newer_filelist ) {
    print STAT_FILE join ';', $my_filelist->{filename}, $my_filelist->{inode}, "$my_filelist->{count}\n";
}
close( STAT_FILE );
```

My log files are

#### logrotate_1.0.log

```
#2.0^H#2018 05 29 10:09:45:969#+0200#Info#/Sys/Sec/Authentication#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103EC9E50000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER1#5##C47731E44D00000bae##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@1473726842],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Login
User: USER4
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.0^H#2018 05 29 11:51:06:541#+0200#Info#/Sy/Sec/Authentication#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103EC9F50000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER4#6##A40B81404D03c0bae##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@1264376989],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Login
User: USER1
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.0^H#2018 05 30 11:54:03:906#+0200#Info#/Sy/Sec/Informtion#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103EC9F50000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER4#6##A40B81404D03c0bae##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@1264376989],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Login
User: USER4
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.0^H#2018 05 30 11:59:59:156#+0200#Info#/Sys/Sec/Authentication#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103ECA0C#3935150000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER3#7##9ACF7Ec0bae##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@124054179],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Logout
User: USER3
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.0^H#2018 05 30 08:32:11:348#+0200#Warn#/Sys/Sec/Authentication#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103ECA20E0000508C#3935150000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER2#03c0bae##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@2033389552],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Login
User: USER4
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.0^H#2018 05 30 11:09:54:978#+0200#Info#/Sys/Sec/Information#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103ECA20E0000508C#3935150000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER2#03c0bae##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@2033389552],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Login
User: USER2
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.0^H#2018 06 01 08:11:30:008#+0200#Warn#/Sys/Sec/Authentication#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103ECA20050000508C#3935150000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER2#0##E0E##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@2033389552],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Logout
User: USER2
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.0^H#2018 06 01 11:11:29:658#+0200#Info#/Sys/Sec/Information#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103ECA20050000508C#3935150000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER2#0##E0E##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@2033389552],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Logout
User: USER1
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.0^H#2018 06 02 12:00:00:254#+0200#Info#/Sys/Sec/Authentication#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103ECA20050000508C#3935150000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER2#0##E0E##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@2033389552],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Logout
User: Guest
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.0^H#2018 06 02 12:05:00:465#+0200#Warn#/Sys/Sec/Authentication#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103ECA20050000508C#3935150000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER2#0##E0E##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@2033389552],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Logout
User: USER9
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.0^H#2018 06 02 12:50:00:065#+0200#Warn#/Sys/Sec/Authentication#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103ECA20050000508C#3935150000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER2#0##E0E##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@2033389552],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Login
User: USER9
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.0^H#2018 05 24 10:43:38:683#+0200#Info#/Sys/Sec/Authentication#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103EC9E50000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER1#5##C47731E44D00000bae##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@1473726842],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Login
User: USER1
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:
```

#### logrotate_0.0.log

```
#2.0^H#2018 05 24 11:05:04:011#+0200#Info#/Sy/Sec/Authentication#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103EC9F50000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER4#6##A40B81404D03c0bae##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@1264376989],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Login
User: USER4
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.0^H#2018 05 24 11:04:59:410#+0200#Info#/Sy/Sec/Informtion#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103EC9F50000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER4#6##A40B81404D03c0bae##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@1264376989],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Login
User: USER4
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.0^H#2018 05 24 11:05:07:100#+0200#Info#/Sys/Sec/Authentication#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103ECA0C#3935150000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER3#7##9ACF7Ec0bae##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@124054179],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Logout
User: USER3
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.0^H#2018 05 24 11:07:21:314#+0200#Warn#/Sys/Sec/Authentication#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103ECA20E0000508C#3935150000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER2#03c0bae##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@2033389552],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Login
User: USER2
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.0^H#2018 05 24 11:07:21:314#+0200#Info#/Sys/Sec/Information#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103ECA20E0000508C#3935150000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER2#03c0bae##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@2033389552],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Login
User: USER2
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.0^H#2018 05 26 10:48:02:458#+0200#Warn#/Sys/Sec/Authentication#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103ECA20050000508C#3935150000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER2#0##E0E##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@2033389552],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Logout
User: USER2
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.0^H#2018 05 28 10:00:25:000#+0200#Info#/Sys/Sec/Information#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103ECA20050000508C#3935150000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER2#0##E0E##0#Thread[HTTP Worker [@2033389552],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain##
Logout
User: USER0
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:
```

My Errors are:

```
#2.#2018 08 02 21:00:41:740#+0200#Info#/System/Security/Authentication#
Use of uninitialized value within @lines in pattern match (m//) at ./mylog.pl line 70, <$fh> line 10766.
Use of uninitialized value within @lines in pattern match (m//) at ./mylog.pl line 70, <$fh> line 10766.
Use of uninitialized value within @lines in pattern match (m//) at ./mylog.pl line 70, <$fh> line 10766.
```

And cause of this error is that row, that not detect my data, if i don't put $/ = "\n\n"; as record separator

> if ( $lines[$i] =~
>   m/\A#\d.\d.+#\d{4}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3}#+\d+#\w+#/\w+/\w+/Authentication/
>   ) {

Comment: Try changing the skiprow == to eq.  You're only doing string comparisons, right?

Comment: @user1717259 I did not understand...  I have $jumprow = $older_count{$INPUT}[0] if $currentinode == $inode;

Comment: That's far too much code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @melpomene i've indicated the specific problem and row of my bug... if i exclude a block, problem doesn't appear :( . Your request is impossible to be applied... :( sound like understand why a building has crashed, publishing photo of three bricks

Comment: You have not indicated the specific problem. You've only given your interpretation of what's going on, not the facts, and I don't understand your description. You've also not provided sufficient instructions to reproduce the problem. In my opinion what you've posted here is not verifiable and possibly incomplete.

Comment: @melpomene i've add more information :( to my question

Comment: ... yeah, that's still not minimal. For example, do you really need `use English` to reproduce the problem? Or `strftime`? What about the code after the `foreach` loop that throws the warning? Why do you need that?

Comment: I need english for $OS_ERROR. Code after foreach is needed because i have to get line after my line detected  $lines [$i + n].

Comment: I asked if those parts where needed to "*to reproduce the problem*", not for your program. For example, anything that happens after the error is irrelevant. You can replace `$OS_ERROR` by `$!` and thereby remove the need for `use English` (and make the code more readable at the same time (also, you're already using `$!` all over the place)).

Comment: @melpomene ok...i've remove 40th rows...

Comment: I think  you're misunderstanding what an *MCVE* is. You should study [***How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example***](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and apply it to your problem. It isn't just a matter of hacking superficially unnecessary statements out of your code, and you should probably be doing it yourself as part of our own debugging process.

Comment: Ok this post you do not like, I delete everything.
Thank you